# How do I automatically expand my WPF tabitem to fit the header text?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79XRw.png)

Basically, this is what it looks like, I want my tabitem to automatically make the header text fit inside the tabitem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF tabitem widths are adaptive unless you specify a width. If you don't specify a width, check if you have fixed the width of the content control or container when you define the TabItem style.

```
<TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="long"/>
            <TabItem Header="longlonglonglong"/>
</TabControl>
```

[image]

Initial control template

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
     <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
         <Border x:Name="mainBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0">
             <Border x:Name="innerBorder" Background="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Background}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Border}" BorderThickness="1" Margin="-1" Opacity="0"/>
         </Border>
         <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentSource="Header" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
      </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```